# Odd behaviour of insertNewObjectForEntityForName leading to NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: core-data, swift

I have a rather odd case of getting a core data error whilst experimenting with Swift. I am not sure whether it comes from Swift (beta error?) or whether it is me. However, here is the setup for my test cases (in VTModelTests.swift).

```
var bundle = NSBundle(forClass: VTModelTests.self)
var url = bundle.URLForResource("VTDocument", withExtension:"momd")
appleModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: url)
assert (appleModel != nil)
var coord = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: appleModel);
var store = coord.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSInMemoryStoreType,configuration:nil,URL:nil,options:nil,error:nil);
assert (store != nil)
ctx = NSManagedObjectContext();
ctx!.persistentStoreCoordinator=coord
ctx!.retainsRegisteredObjects=true;

var drwName = "Drawing"
var descs = ctx!.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName
for e : AnyObject in descs.allKeys{
    assert (descs.objectForKey(e).name == e as String )
    if (e as String == drwName) {
        NSLog("yeah")
    }
}
model = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(drwName,inManagedObjectContext: ctx) as Drawing
```

My error message looks like this:

```
2014-06-22 22:12:25.584 xctest[63792:303] yeah
<unknown>:0: error: -[_TtC12VTModelTests12BaseTypeTest testTreeStructure] : failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Drawing' in this model."
```

In short, I can "prove" that the entity name is there (the 'yeah' in the log), but core data is showing the issue that the name would not be in the model. Previous versions of the loop printed out the entities and that looked good. I don't have any second versions, and a new changed name ('Model' is now called 'Drawing') is correctly shown in the model data when all entities are printed. The compiled model is in the resulting bundle.

Can anybody explain? Or do I have to wait for the next beta release of Xcode 6? What else did I overlook? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm the issue. Not an answer but the way around I use is to split insertNewObjectForEntityForName into:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Photo", inManagedObjectContext:context)
let photo = Photo(entity:entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context)
```